# One hot encoding of two arrays (labeling two origins of data)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, scikit-learn

I would like to use one hot encoding to classify the origin of the data.

I have two kinds of data as numpy arrays, `Cp_a` and `Cp_b`.

And these data have `(10000, 74)` and `(7000, 74)` shape, respectively.

The data type of `Cp_a` and `Cp_b` is `float64`.

I would like to combine these data with categorical values, `0` or `1`, using `vstack()` and `one hot encoding`.

The final shape that I want to see is `(17000,75)` with `0` for the data `Cp_a` and `1` for the data `Cp_b`.

How can I do that using scikit learn or keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
>>> a2 = np.random.randint(10,50,size=(5,2))
>>> print(a1)
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
>>> print(a2)
[[23 42]
 [39 28]
 [39 19]
 [49 46]
 [33 29]]
>>> a1 = np.column_stack((a1,np.zeros((a1.shape[0],1))))
>>> a2 = np.column_stack((a2,np.ones((a2.shape[0],1))))
>>> np.vstack((a1,a2))
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  9.,  0.],
       [23., 42.,  1.],
       [39., 28.,  1.],
       [39., 19.,  1.],
       [49., 46.,  1.],
       [33., 29.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in numpy using the `append` function.

```py
import numpy as np

Cp_a = np.append(Cp_a, np.zeros((len(Cp_a), 1), axis=1)
Cp_b = np.append(Cp_b, np.ones((len(Cp_b), 1), axis=1)
Cp_ab = np.vstack([Cp_a, Cp_b])
```

Comment: It has an error : TypeError: 'axis' is an invalid keyword argument for zeros()

Comment: @mario119 axis is parameter for append and not for zeros or ones, so use the parenthesis accordingly